# ADS Simulation of IV Diode Characteristics

Tags: rf, diodes, simulation, rectifier, ads

I’m still quite new to ADS, and I’m trying to get a simple simulation of the IV diode characteristics.

I want to plot the diode current against a DC sweep from -0.2V to +0.2V

Here’s what I’ve got so far, not so sure as to why the current is negative.

Is the circuit OK?

[image]

[image]

Would appreciate some help and guidance.

Comment: Google "passive current convention"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a circuit connected to a DC voltage source, the current direction is from the positive terminal to the negative terminal of the source; therefore, Kirchhoff Current Law requires that the current **in the voltage source** flows from its negative terminal to its positive terminal. Your simulation measures the current SRC1 through the source (equal to a minus current through the diode according to KCL) against the voltage VCC across the swept source, so the current values are negative in the positive voltage range of your simulation plot.

For your simulation, you selected the **Schottky diode** (HSMS2850). The **"knee" voltage** of Schottky diodes is around 0.2 - 0.4 V, you can see it in your graph. For **silicon diodes** (like 1N400X), the "knee" voltage is about 0.6-0.7 V.